# How to access the result of a function called in a multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, list, function, multiprocessing

I am runnning this code :

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time

def list_append(count, id):
    out_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        out_list.append(random.random())
    return out_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t0 = time.clock()
    size = 10000000   # Number of random numbers to add
    procs = 2   # Number of processes to create

    jobs = []
    for i in range(0, procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append,args=(size, i))                                        
        jobs.append(process)

# Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)  
    res=[]  
    for j in jobs:
        r= j.start()
        res.append(r)

# Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print "List processing complete."
    print time.clock()-t0,"seconds"
```

Unfortunately, at the end of it, `res = [None,None]` although I want it to be filled with the lists I've filled in the function `list_append`.

Comment: Does it work for you getting the results via a `multiprocesssing.Pool` like on this [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)? I read the documentation of the [Process class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) and found no way of getting the result, only the exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [data structures that can be shared between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
def list_append(count, id, res):
    #                      ^^^
    out_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        out_list.append(random.random())
    res[id] = out_list  # <------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10000000
    procs = 2   
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()  # <---
    res = manager.dict()                 # <---
    jobs = []
    for i in range(0, procs):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append,args=(size, i, res))
        #                                                                   ^^^^
        jobs.append(process)

    for j in jobs:
        r = j.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print "List processing complete."
    # now `res` will contain results
```

As avenet commented, using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) will be simpler:

```
def list_append(args):
    count, id = args
    out_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        out_list.append(random.random())
    return out_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 10000000
    procs = 2

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(procs)
    res = pool.map(list_append, [(size, i) for i in range(procs)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print "List processing complete."
    # print res
```