# Get result from multiprocessing process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to know if is there a way to make multiprocessing working in this code. What should I change or if there exist other function in multiprocessing that will allow me to do that operation.

You can call the `locateOnScreen('calc7key.png')` function to get the screen coordinates. The return value is a 4-integer tuple: `(left, top, width, height)`.

I got error:

```
checkNumber1 = resourceBlankLightTemp[1]

TypeError: 'Process' object does not support indexing
```

---

```py
import pyautogui, time, os, logging, sys, random, copy
import multiprocessing as mp

BLANK_DARK = os.path.join('images', 'blankDark.png')
BLANK_LIGHT = os.path.join('images', 'blankLight.png')

def blankFirstDarkResourcesIconPosition():
    blankDarkIcon = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(BLANK_DARK)
    return blankDarkIcon


def blankFirstLightResourcesIconPosition():
    blankLightIcon = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(BLANK_LIGHT)
    return blankLightIcon


def getRegionOfResourceImage():

    global resourceIconRegion

    resourceBlankLightTemp = mp.Process(target = blankFirstLightResourcesIconPosition)
    resourceBlankDarkTemp = mp.Process(target = blankFirstDarkResourcesIconPosition)

    resourceBlankLightTemp.start()
    resourceBlankDarkTemp.start()

    if(resourceBlankLightTemp == None):
        checkNumber1 = 2000
    else:
        checkNumber1 = resourceBlankLightTemp[1]

    if(resourceBlankDarkTemp == None):
        checkNumber2 = 2000
    else:
        checkNumber2 = resourceBlankDarkTemp[1]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process `mp.Process` returns a Process object, not an iterable. I think you're looking to use `Pipe`, but I'm not well versed in MP.

Comment: So the actual question is: How to get the result of a function call handled in a `Process`. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30189270/1639625) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the result of a function called in a multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767206/how-to-access-the-result-of-a-function-called-in-a-multiprocessing-in-python)

Comment: @tobias_k Shockingly enough, there exists a question with almost that *exact* same title.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you just want to use multiprocessing to run existing CPU-intensive functions in parallel, it is easiest to do through a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), as shown in the example at the beginning of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
# ...

def getRegionOfResourceImage():

    global resourceIconRegion

    with mp.Pool(2) as p:
        resourceBlankLightTemp, resourceBlankDarkTemp = p.map(
            lambda x: x(), [blankFirstLightResourcesIconPosition,
                            blankFirstDarkResourcesIconPosition])

    if(resourceBlankLightTemp == None):
        # ...
```